# what is the status of my ban?

Tags: support, questions

I recall a ban on asking questions on serverfault.  Aside from asking a question to see what happens, how do I know whether that ban is still in effect?  Looking at my rep, I see:

```
5   Jun 8
+5  11:49   upvote  postfix: Temporary lookup failure for FQDN
    11:47   accept  mailman web UI on localhost with apache2
    11:45   accept  postfix: Temporary lookup failure for FQDN
    11:13   accept  export Usenet via IMAP or POP3
5   Apr 2
+5  12:16   upvote  postfix: Temporary lookup failure for FQDN
15  Nov 8 '12
+10     07:52   upvote  export Usenet via IMAP or POP3
+5  07:52   upvote  export Usenet via IMAP or POP3
-4    Sep 17 '12
-2  19:03   downvote    mailman web UI on localhost with apache2
-2  18:02   downvote    mailman web UI on localhost with apache2
```

which makes me think it might have been lifted?

I saw a message like this:

[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

or similar, in the past.  I just don't want to go through the trouble of forming and asking a question just to get that message again, so I would like to know the status of my ban.

At what stage in asking a question do you see the error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are currently not blocked from participating in the site in any way.

You were last blocked in December 2013; it would have to have been a very very serious, moderator implemented incident for it to last 6 months.

Just be careful, as it's not very hard to get back onto the automatic block list if more of your questions are poorly received.

Comment: thx.  I didn't know it had a time limit.

Comment: With only one notable exception, all bans are strictly temporary, but they increase in length with each occasion.